# vue components v-on:click works localy but does not work on heroku

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku

I deployed my laravel/vue.js app to heroku and it stopped working properly. The send button from vue component is not doing anythig.
Locally it works. When I click at **send** it sends the post request and changes  to **sent**.
But on **heroku** at clicking nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

This is my vue.js component

```
<template>
<div>
    <p v-on:click="sendArticle()"  v-text="buttonText" v-show="status"> </p>
    <a v-bind:href="url" v-show="status">Edit</a>

    <a v-bind:href="articleId"  v-show="!status">Sent</a>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    props: [
        'articleId',
        'sent',
        'url',
    ],

    data: function() {
        return  {
            status: this.sent,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        sendArticle() {
            axios.post('send/'+ this.articleId)
                .then(response => {

                    if (!this.status) {
                        this.url = '';
                        return
                    }

                    this.status = ! this.status;

                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    if (errors.response.status == 401) {
                        window.location = '/login';
                    }
                });
        }
    },

    computed: {
        buttonText() {
            return (this.status) ? 'Send' : 'Sent';
        },

    }
}
```

Comment: `send/` wont work. you need to provide complete `api url` to `axios.post('send/'+ this.articleId)`

Comment: are there any errors in developer console, any network requests triggered?

Comment: There is no error is in console (and api works in localhost I don't think that the request is the problem).  Clicking the button isn't doing anything in debug console.

Answer (score 1):

The button is working, the send part is the issue. it seems like you are trying to call a local api from the hosted version.

A good way to handle this would be to make an environment variable, let's say "VUE_APP_BASEURL" with the url to the api endpoint.

you can set the "VUE_APP_BASEURL" variable locally inside [a .env file](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)

so in your `.env` file for example, you will have VUE_APP_BASEURL=http://localhost:3030/

and [on heroku you can set the env to whatever endpoint your hosted api is.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)
for example : `VUE_APP_BASEURL = https://random-heroku-domain-73823.herokuapp.com/`

After doing so you can use the same axios logic without changing a thing for local as well as hosted! You would call the .env variable by doing `process.env.VUE_APP_BASEURL so it will be something like this:

```js
sendArticle() {
            axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BASEURL+'send/'+ this.articleId)
                .then(response => {

                    if (!this.status) {
                        this.url = '';
                        return
                    }

                    this.status = ! this.status;

                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(errors => {
                    if (errors.response.status == 401) {
                        window.location = '/login';
                    }
                });
        }
```

Happy Coding!